# react, как загружать csv файл?

Tags: reactjs, csv, loader

Как в react лучше загрузить данные из csv файла в приложение? Что бы это все было как массив? Может есть какие-то библиотеки?

Comment: webpack используете?

Comment: использую create-react-app

Comment: посмотрите в сторону csv-loader, papaparse

Comment: https://www.papaparse.com/docs#csv-to-json

Comment: спасибо, поставьте как ответ я приму

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [papaparse](http://papaparse.com/docs#csv-to-json) есть документация и примеры